# need help to compare a cell with text to an array with text and if no match retrive a 1 and if match show blank if referance is blank retrive a blank

Tags: excel

I need to compare a cell with text to an array with text and if no match retrieve a 1 and if match show blank if reference is blank retrieve a blank.
What I am using right now is:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D:D,A2)>0,"",1)
```

But this returns a 1 if the cell of reference is blank I need to to return a blank.

below is an example :

[image: sample]

Comment: That Cleared the blank cell issue but now if it finds a cell with text with no match in column D it does not return the 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(A2="",COUNTIF(D:D,A2)>0,"",1)
```

It will test if either A2 is Blank or in the array and return the `""` else it will return `1`.